# What happens if we do nothing at work?

Tags: communication

Supposing we have passed the trial period at work, and we've got hired. And after that, so, we are in front of the screen of our computer, we does nothing, we twiddle one's thumbs, we click randomly in the screen parts... What does we risk ?

Comment: Can you state why you believe "being fired" is not an answer?

Comment: Welcome to Workplace. Please, please, when you ask questions try to relate them to actual workplace problems.

Answer (score 6):

You risk being on the list of people who do nothing of value for the company. This list is identical to the list of the first ones to go in case of trouble.

Moreover it could also be that you manager will try to fire you anyway.

Answer (score 4):

> Supposing we have passed the trial period at work, and we've got
>   hired. And after that, so, we are in front of the screen of our
>   computer, we does nothing, we twiddle one's thumbs, we click randomly
>   in the screen parts... What does we risk ?

It depends on local laws, company customs, unions, etc.

If you worked anywhere I have ever worked, you would be talked to by your boss, perhaps put on a Performance Improvement Plan, and eventually fired for incompetence.